# WPF DatePicker How to Set default date to 5 days from today

Tags: wpf, xaml

I know I can use `SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"` to set today's date.  But how to set the date to today + 5 days in xaml?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to bind a nullable DateTime property and use TargetNullValue with a static helper

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding MyDate, 
    TargetNullValue={x:Static MyApplication:Dates.FiveDaysInFuture}}"/>
```

And the static helper

```
public static class Dates
{
    public static DateTime FiveDaysInFuture
    {
        get { return DateTime.Today.AddDays(5); }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Or just initialize the view model properly, because using the above would mean the date is actually not set in the view model until user actually changes the value.

Comment: @JanneMatikained So, it looks like this can not be done in xaml only.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
  <DatePicker Loaded="dtPicker_Loaded"  x:Name="dtPicker"></DatePicker>
  <x:Code>
  private void dtPicker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    dtPicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
  }
 </x:Code>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't do this in pure XAML. You would have to use code of some sort.

Comment: In a WPF, where would you then typically set intitial values of your form controls.  I was doing this in Load event of my form in regular forms but I am not sure if that is the best way to do it?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. The Window constructor is as good a place as any. It looks like you are _not_ making use of the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern: I would seriously consider looking into that, and also data binding, as you will then get more out of WPF.

Comment: I am using WPF application, not an ASP.NET application.  Most of articles I saw talk about MVVM when talking about ASP.NET.  I am complete beginner, so please advise me on this and get me some good links if you know as I would like to do this the right way.  In old Windows Forms, I would just do it in FormLoad event.  Much appreciated

Comment: The more recent versions of ASP.NET implement MVC (Model-View-Controller), not MVVM, although the two have a number of similarities. If you need to learn more about MVVM then a quick internet search for the keywords `wpf mvvm` will give you a bunch of relevant links.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `SelectedDate = "{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)}"`

Comment: @Eraiwan I tried that but I get "Nested types and not supported: DateTime.Now" and "Cannot find the member "AddDays(5)" on the target type.